# An example of weakly convergent probability measures that do not form a family of relatively compact probability measures.

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

We have space {$C_{[0,1]},\mathfrak B(C_{[0,1]}) $}. What is an example of weakly convergent probability measures, that don't form a family of relatively compact probability measures ?$$$$
$C_{[0,1]}$- it's the set of all continuous functions on the interval [0,1],
$\quad\mathfrak B(C_{[0,1]}) $ $\sigma-$ algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? What makes you believe that such a sequence exists?

Comment: I'm trying to understand theorem about weak convergence on  space of continuous function. From its conditions it follows that such an example exists.